# laravelのコントローラのログを出力する方法

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

config/logging.phpにはstorage/log/laravel.logを指定しています。
ファイル自体は存在し、シンタックスエラー等を出すとログファイルは更新されています。
xxxController.phpにlog::info('a::'.$a);やlog::debug('a::'.$a);を入力してもログに出力されません。
どうすれば中身を確認できるでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

バックスラッシュつきで出力されませんか？

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    \Log::debug("test");
}
```

もし出力されない場合は `config/app.php` に以下のような記述があるか確認してください

```php
    'aliases' => [
    // 省略
            'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    // 省略
    ],
```

Comment: バックスラッシュ付きで出力されました、ありがとうございます